# Screen doesn't launched since using react-native-navigation

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am migrating from old navigator to react-native-navigation.
I've follow the guide from [here](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/installation-ios), but now my app only loads the splash screen and never loads the first screen.

I am getting warning message:

> Required dispatch_syng to load constants for RNDeviceInfo. This may lead to deadlocks

I think there's no warning message like this before, but I'm not sure.

Here's my AppDelegate.m:

```js
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <CodePush/CodePush.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>
#import <RNGoogleSignin/RNGoogleSignin.h>
#import <Firebase.h>
#import "RCCManager.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                        openURL:url
                                              sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                     annotation:annotation
          ]
  || [RNGoogleSignin application:application
                         openURL:url
               sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                      annotation:annotation
      ];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
  [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray * _Nullable))restorationHandler
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application
                   continueUserActivity:userActivity
                     restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                           didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

#ifdef DEBUG
    jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
    jsCodeLocation = [CodePush bundleURL];
#endif

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  [[RCCManager sharedInstance] initBridgeWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation launchOptions:launchOptions];

  [FIRApp configure];
  return YES;
}

@end
```

I am using:

```
react 16.0.0
react-native 0.47.2
react-native-navigation 1.1.262
```

I am installing react-native navigation using npm version 5.3.0

Comment: Sorry, I think the issue was in the implementation on the react native, on index.js

Comment: I have the same issue I believe, can you elaborate on your fix?

Comment: @pgGriff I am ended up using react-navigation for customization purposes. But I was able to fix this issue. I think there was an issue with my index.js. I don't remember exactly how.